# How to select an object automatically FK item (django)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, forms

I have a question and answer quiz and when I put it in HTML I have such a result [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKsQY.png)
To save a question, I must first manually select the question. So I want this to happen automatically. Each question will appear automatically. But I could not understand the view I have to change if html and what I have to change

this is my code -->

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answer_question=models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    
class Answer(models.Model):
    questin=models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.questin)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Question,Answer

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Question
        fields="__all__"


class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Answer
        fields="__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import QuestionForm,AnswerForm
from .models import Question


def home(request):
    form=QuestionForm
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request, "question/base.html", {"form":form})

def ans(request):
    form=AnswerForm
    e=Question.objects.all()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
    return render(request, "question/ans.html", {"form":form, "e":e})
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>question</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% for i in e %}
        <form method="POST" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
                
               {% for a in form %}

               {{a}}

               {% endfor %}
            
            <input type="submit" name="sub">
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
        
        

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could do something like: random_question = Question.objects.get(pk=random.randint(1, 10)) [you need to import random library before that of course] and pass that to the template

Comment: @icecube Yes, but in this case you do it randomly (1,10) but yes I can have 20 questions. Can you help me correct veiw?

Comment: @icecube can you help me?

Comment: then you could do: random_question = Question.objects.get(pk=random.randint(1,Question.objects.count() ) < and that would get a random question from all the questions that you created >

Comment: @icecube "'Question' object is not iterable" i replace e=Question.objects.all() with your answer. did i do it wrong?

Comment: try something like that: random_question = Question.objects.get(pk=random.randint(1, int(Question.objects.count())))

Comment: @icecube It's the same nothing has changed

Comment: have you changed that ".all()" to ".count()"?

Comment: @icecube I copied what you wrote directly

Comment: and what did that return?

Comment: @icecube https://ibb.co/Nm1Xszj see image

Comment: @icecube Do you have any idea?

Comment: you are trying to use a loop on a single question, change that "{% for i in e %}" in your template to just {{random_question}} <but you need to pass that to the context firstly> so It would be something like that: 1. random_question = Question.objects.get(pk=random.randint(1, int(Question.objects.count()))) 2. context = {"random_question": random_question} 3. (in template) {{random_question}}

Comment: @icecube change and https://ibb.co/dWrRYM4 . Not working properly

Comment: firstly we should check if it works, try adding "print(random_question.question)" to the view and check in the console if it shows a random question < when you refresh the page it should do that >, then we will insert the value of that to that form

Comment: @icecube only show my name -> https://ibb.co/F7TMMHd

Comment: I might have misunderstood, are trying to create a form that creates a question and lets you to add answer to that question ?

Comment: @icecube Yes, I do not want to have to manually select a question and have all the questions appear automatically. Only 1 question "my name" appeared here and neither is stored in the database

Comment: @icecube Show all questions and the answer form of the question

Comment: so when opening that page user sees all questions and he can pick one and answer it? or it just choses a random question and lets the user answer it?

Comment: @icecube Yes he sees all the questions but the question has already been chosen Wait 2 minutes and see the photo about how I want it

Comment: @icecube see https://ibb.co/zQ22RX7. question -> input -> submit. I have to manually select the question in my code and I do not want to

Comment: @icecube Did you understand how I want to?

Comment: @icecube can you help me?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do so... I don't think I'm able to help.

Comment: @icecube ok thank you <3